# Variable randomly contains all file names... it should not

Tags: r, bash

So I have a bash script that runs a couple stats programs, and grabs the results of some.

```
RESULT=$(Rscript snowstats.r)
echo $RESULT
```

The R script works fine.  The output is as expected.  But somehow, when Bash grabs this result and stores it in the $RESULT variable, all the filenames in the entire directory are also randomly interspersed throughout $RESULT...

such as

```
Call: lm(formula = snow ~ msnow + temp, data = stuff)(this should be here)
Some more R stuff(this should be here)
random filenames(this should NOT be here)
more random filenames(this should NOT be here)
more R stuff(this should be here)
```

The R script is very simple...

```
stuff = read.table("/home/mclarkson/test.txt",header=TRUE)
results = lm(snow ~ msnow + temp, data=stuff)
summary(results);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Very hard to answer this without seeing your `snowstats.r` file. I just tried this with a very minimal example and did not get an extra file names, etc... when I ran `echo $Result` afterwards.

Comment: The r script is about as simple as possible

    stuff = read.table("/home/user/test.txt",header=TRUE)
    results = lm(snow ~ msnow + temp, data=stuff)
    summary(results);

Comment: Then it shouldn't be any trouble for you to add it to your question.

Comment: It is most likely due to the asterisks begin printed for significant p-values in your model summary, as @NPE suggested. Try adding `options(show.signif.stars=FALSE)` to the top of your script. This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect `$RESULT` contains an asterisk (`*`), which bash then [expands](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0080.php) to all the filenames in the current directory.